# How to use relative paths to scripts in HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to refer to my JS/CSS with a relative path, like `./myScript.js`, such that, if I host the site on `https://myHost.com/myPath`, it should look for the script in `https://myHost.com/myPath/myScript.js`, but if I host it on `http://localhost/`, it should look in `http://localhost/myScript.js`. It is always looking in the root though, as if I had made an absolute path.

Is it not possible to make relative paths? I would prefer if I did not need to change the actual HTML file between environments.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW3uX.png)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="./static/css/main.6dea0f05.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>/* a bunch of auto generated react code */</script>
    <script src="./static/js/2.1ca84f3b.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/main.487a42e6.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times that I spend 2 hours fiddling with it, to no avail, post a question, and then find the answer directly after..

The issue is that I automatically return `index.html` if users do not specify it, making chrome think that the current "folder" is the root when accessing `https://myHost.com/myPath`. If I go to `https://myHost.com/myPath/index.html` it works.

So, I need to do a proper redirect to `index.html`, instead of just returning it. Or to anything under `myPath`, like `https://myHost.com/myPath/home`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```html
<base href="https://www.w3schools.com/">
```

I hopes, that it helps for you!

Comment: I read about base as well, but I do not want to change the HTML between environments. Anyway, it turns out it was not related to the actual HTML, but instead the way I default to `index.html`.